Handle livewire events in both PHP and JS
I have this component called beat-player, on the PHP code I receive a dispatched event from another component and it works:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;

class BeatPlayer extends Component
{
    public $scores;
    public $difficulty;
    public $note_type;

    public $sample_urls ;

    // public function mount($score)
    // {
    //     $this->score = $score;
    // }
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->sample_urls = [
            'snare' => asset('samples/snare.wav'),
            'kick' => asset('samples/kick2.wav'),
            'hat' => asset('samples/hihat2.wav')
        ];
    }
    
    #[On('score-updated')]
    public function handleUpates($updates){
        $this->scores = $updates['scores'];
        $this->difficulty = $updates['difficulty'];
        $this->note_type = $updates['note-type'];
    }
    public function updateScore($scores)
    {
        $this->scores = $scores;
    }
    public function updateDifficulty($difficulty){
        $this->difficulty=$difficulty;
    }
    public function updateNoteType($note_type)
    {
        $this->note_type = $note_type;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        // dd($this);
        return view('livewire.beat-player');
    }
}


on the blade code I am trying to handle it as well so I can trigger some updates on a 3rd party library:
    @script
        <script>
              ......
               snip
              ......
            window.sequencer = a();
            
            $wire.on('score-updated',(updates)=>{
                console.log('updates')
            });
        </script>
    @endscript


this event is not being triggered.
is it possible to handle in both parts?
in essence there is a property that gets updated ($scores) that I need to know when that happens.
thanks in advance

Change $wire.on('score-updated', ... to Livewire.on('score-updated', if the event is triggered from another component.

I think, if I understood your description correctly, the issue is that the score-updated event is dispatched from another component.
Looking at the docs on this
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events#listening-for-events-inside-component-scripts
it says:

You can easily listen for the post-created event inside your component's template from a @script directive like so:

@script
<script>
    $wire.on('post-created', () => {
        //
    });
</script>
@endscript


The above snippet would listen for the post-created from the component it's registered within. If the component is no longer on the page, the event listener will no longer be triggered.

One way you can test this would be to dispatch a new event from your handleUpates function:
    #[On('score-updated')]
    public function handleUpates($updates){
        $this->scores = $updates['scores'];
        $this->difficulty = $updates['difficulty'];
        $this->note_type = $updates['note-type'];
        $this->dispatch("pass-through-score-updated");
    }

Then listen for pass-through-score-updated in your script.
If that works then you could leave it at that or look into dispatching events to other components:
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events#dispatching-directly-to-another-component
Hopefully that helps

thanks, yes, but the component is not unloaded, it's still on the page. this is a hierarchy of components that is still on the page, and the SAME component but server side is properly updating on the event, but I wanted to trigger client side.
I ended up just using the same property instead of a copy of it, but still not found why it is not triggering .

Okay, well sounds like you got something to work in the end, that's good news!

This generic JS listener can work:
@script
<script>

    document.addEventListener('score-updated', (event) => {

        console.log('updates', event.detail);

    })

</script>
@endscript

